# Was the bathroom stall scene in Get Hard real or green screen?

Tags: production, get-hard

In ***Get Hard***, Will Ferrell plays a stock broker that gets framed for embezzlement and gets convicted for it. He's sentenced for five to ten in San Quentin max security prison. To get prepared, he hires a black guy who he thinks went to prison to prepare him for Quentin. One of the steps was preparing to give head.

In the scene, Will Ferrell is preparing to do it to a gay man in a bathroom stall in a California gay spot. At one point, Will Ferrell's character ends up touching face to organ. **Did Ferrell actually shove his face into some guys crotch, or was it an instance of green screen or video editing magic?**

Comment: Knowing Will Ferrell it was probably real.

Answer (score 1):

According to Ferrell (in [this interview with the Toronto Sun](http://www.torontosun.com/2015/03/22/will-ferrell-stands-up-for-justin-bieber-praises-kevin-hart)), it was actually a prosthetic penis. He does, however state that a real penis was used during the rehearsals, implying that the scene was not a green-screen effect:

> *Taking the prison rape gag to new extremes, Darnell convinces James to
>   go to a gay bar and get a taste of performing oral sex on men. James
>   is hit on by a pushy regular (Matt Walsh) and taken into a bathroom
>   stall to get down to business.*
>
> *Thing is, as wince-worthy as the scene may be for all the wrong
>   reasons, it’s very hard not to laugh at Ferrell reacting like a kid
>   who doesn’t want to swallow a dose of a particularly nasty medicine.*
>
> ***“It’s all a blur,” says Ferrell with a chuckle when recalling the
>   scene. “Let’s just say the prosthetic (penis) was only used when we
>   were going to shoot it.”***

and in [this interview](http://www.avclub.com/article/balls-pubes-and-buttcracks-mechanics-overnights-fa-221883) (with professional prop-maker Matthew Mungle), we learn the process of how Ferrell *auditioned* the fake penis:

> **AVC:** **Was The Overnight the first time you’ve ever made a fake penis
>   for a movie?**
>
> **MM:** *No, no. We’ve done We’re The Millers, Get Hard.*
>
> *That’s a funny story because [for Get Hard] Will Ferrell wanted to
>   make sure it could be wiped in his face, because that’s what happens
>   in the film. And we sent him one that was a little too hard, so we
>   sent him another one, and a video of it. He rubbed it over his face,
>   and said, “That’s perfect.” It was soft enough. So then he sent it
>   back, and we painted it.*